# Tree Data Structure Problem, Can help in solving this

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree

1. Define a node data structure that has the following properties: color, name. where name = any number color = any random color from list [blue, yellow, green]
2. Using the node data structure defined at (1) generate a tree having L number of levels and N number of children per node. N is a random number between minChildren and maxChildren method: Node genTree( int levelsCount, int minChildren, int maxChildren )
   where: levelsCount = total number of levels minChildren = min number of children per parent node maxChildren = max number of children per parent node
   usage: Node tree = genTree(10, 2, 5)

Comment: What is exactly your question? You define the data you need pretty well...

Comment: Can you also provide an example input and output ?